# Poweriso returns unrecognized parameter

Tags: live-usb

Using either:

```
poweriso extract filename.iso -od dirname
poweriso extract "filename.iso" -od "dirname"
```

returns invariably:

```
PowerISO   Copyright(C) 2004-2008 PowerISO Computing, Inc
            Type poweriso -? for help

Unrecognized parameter: dirname
```

I've found another question about this but the only answer only states to put quotation marks around filename and dirname, which has as previously stated not worked. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Silly question, but is `dirname` what you're actually typing?  Or are you specifying a folder as in the instructions: http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/command-line-argus.htm

Comment: I am following instructions, dirname and filename are just to be generical.

Answer (score 2):

Oh god, sorry to you all. It was me overlooking a really small detail. Thanks to ThatGuy who got me looking again at the instructions page and noticing this.

Problem was I was using

```
poweriso extract filename.iso -od dirname
```

HOWEVER, I should be using

```
poweriso extract filename.iso / -od dirname
```

Comment: I was just about to post that.  LOL!  The `/ -od` is a requirement, yes.